# Validate string or autoescape characters

Tags: c, string, validation

Here is my part of the code that is supposed to validate a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const char *myarg1 = NULL;
const char *myarg2 = NULL;

int checkString(char str1[])
{
    int i, x=0, p;
    p=strlen(str1);
    for (i = 0; i < p ; i++)
    {
        if ((str1[i] == '(' && str1[i] <= ')') || (str1[i] >= '!'))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else{ return 0; }
    }
    printf("Invalid char detected in password\n");
    return 1;
}
int main( int argc, const char **argv)
{

  myarg1 = argv[1];
  myarg2 = argv[2];

  if (argc <= 2)
  {
    printf ("usage: %s <string> <encrypt_key>\n", argv[0]);
    return 0;
  }
  checkString(myarg1);
  puts("Just a test message") 

}
```

so if I run the program   with parameter 'Xena(.)!(.)'

to get en exit message "Invalid char detected in password" or... just to autoescape  ALL special chars of the input string!!

Seems to work somehow, but even if the error message is printed the program continues to execute with:

```
puts("Just a test message")
```

Comment: Please note that `str1[i] <= ')'` and `str1[i] >= '!'` is not something that is specified by the C language. There are systems still in active use that doesn't use ASCII, and where those comparisons will not work as you expect.

Comment: As for parts of your problems, you never check what `checkString` returns, you just continue the program no matter what.

Comment: Hint: what exactly do you expect to happen in your program's execution when (and just after) the `return 1` is executed?

Comment: `(str1[i] == '(' && str1[i] <= ')')` is probably not what you intended.

Comment: My c skills a re a bit rusty, so basically if test fails "invalid chars detected" exit program else continue...

Comment: That's not what your code does. To exit the program you must either call the `exit` function, or return from the `main` function.

Comment: @johnnybravo Review `(str1[i] == '(' && str1[i] <= ')')`.  This is certainly the same as `(str1[i] == '(')`.

Comment: @johnnybravo `if (argc <= 2)` test better _before_ `myarg1 = argv[1]; myarg2 = argv[2];`.

Comment: @johnnybravo Please explain what is a "special chars" or not in your application.

Comment: Right, for  instance, if string contains "(" or ")" or "!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but even if the error message is printed the program continues to execute

Because you are not checking the value returned by `checkString()`.

Your code should look similar to this:

```
if (checkString(myarg1) == SUCCESS_VALUE) {
    puts("Just a test message");
} else {
    return FAILURE_VALUE;
}
```

---

As others have already pointed out, not all systems are using ASCII codes. A good solution would be to implement a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table).

**EDIT** Here's an example:

```
bool lookup_char(char x, const char lookup[])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; lookup[i]; ++i) {
        if (x == lookup[i])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool checkString(const char str[])
{
    const char forbidden[] = {'(', ')', '!'};
    for (size_t i = 0; str[i]; ++i) {
        if (lookup_char(str[i], forbidden))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then in your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 3) {
        // At least two arguments
        return ERROR_CODE;
    }

    const char *arg1 = argv[1];
    const char *arg2 = argv[2];
    
    if (!checkString(arg1)) {
        printf("Argument 1 contains forbidden characters.\n");
        return ERROR_CODE;
    }

    printf("Argument 1 is correct.\n");
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Code is supposed to be compiled on linux, 
Idea is programs takes 2 parameters "string1" and "string1". So in case of string1 contains ( or ) to terminate....

Comment: hm...

`int checkString(char *str1[])
{
    int i, p;
    p=strlen(str1);
    for (i = 0; i < p ; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] == '(' || str1[i] == ')')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else{ return 0; }
    }
    printf("Invalid char detected in passsword\n");
    return 1;
}

 printf(":==%d==:\n",checkString(myarg1));`

Always get zero...  I feel quite lost

Comment: @johnnybravo Can you explicitly and formally provide a list of all unaccepted characters?

Comment: For instance,  to check if string contains: "!" "(" ")" , exclamation mark,  right/left parenthesis

Comment: @johnnybravo I've edited the post. See the provided example.

Comment: thanks,  I have the feeling like I'm less then noob :D

Comment: @johnnybravo We were all less than noobs once. But with time, we learn ;)